# iOS 9.1 UIScrollView leaving blank space

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios9.1

I have a `ViewController` with a hierarchy as follows:

- `UIViewController`

  - `UIView`

    - `UIScrollView`

      - `UIView`

        - `UIImageView`
        - `UILabel`

The layout is such that the `UIScrollView` fills the screen. There is no extra logic executed on this ViewController, such as programatic scrolling, listening to scrolling, etc.

When I run this on an iOS 9.0 simulator, the layout is correctly inflated, with the `UIImageView` drawn flush against the top margin.

But when I run this on an iOS 9.1 simulator, there is initially a large whitespace between the top margin and the image. Upon touching the `UIScrollView` it corrects itself, scrolling that the `UIImageView` is flush against the margin.

Setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` does not have an effect (presumably because the scrollview isn't at my root).

My question is: What is different about iOS 9.1 scrollviews that it would be causing this, and what is the work around? Its bothering me since this isn't exactly a complex layout I'm trying to use.

**Edit**

Screen shot of my hierarchy and the constraints applied to them, maybe it helps.
[image: constraints]

Comment: check auto layout constraints, I think constraint is breaking.

Comment: There are no error messages in the console about breaking constraints. I'll add a screen shot of the constraints if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be the hight constraints. try getting rid of them and add them back in, one at a time as needed.